# Nodejs+Expressjs+SocketIO on Heroku gives GET /socket.io/?EIO... 404

Tags: node.js, sockets, heroku

I am having problem with setting socketIO 1.1 up to work on Heroku. I'm running Express v4.2. The socketio runs perfectly on localhost. However, on Heroku, it gives this error:

From Heroku log:

```
2014-09-15T09:40:14.578660+00:00 app[web.1]: GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1410774014583-86 404 6ms - 744b
```

From browser:

```
GET http://[mydomainname]/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1410774080589-97 404 (Not Found) socket.io.js:2680Request.create socket.io.js:2680Request socket.io.js:2614XHR.request socket.io.js:2555XHR.doPoll socket.io.js:2585Polling.poll socket.io.js:2951Polling.doOpen socket.io.js:2895Transport.open socket.io.js:2106Socket.open socket.io.js:1580Socket socket.io.js:1467Socket socket.io.js:1419Manager.open.Manager.connect socket.io.js:272(anonymous function)
```

I have followed the recommended configurations in Socket IO documentations. Relevant code as follows:

```
var express = require('express');
/* routes */
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('static-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cons = require('consolidate');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('dust', cons.dust);
app.set('view engine', 'dust');

app.use(favicon());
app.use(logger('dev'));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(cookieParser('hashionhashion'));
app.use(require('less-middleware')(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//routing
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);


/// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

/// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});



//start the server
var server = require('http').Server(app);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var ioSockets = {};

io.on('connection', function(socket) {

    ioSockets[socket.id] = socket;

    socket.emit('welcome', {message: socket.id});

    socket.on('disconnect', function(socket) {
        delete ioSockets[socket.id];
    });
});

exports.ioSockets = ioSockets;
module.exports = app;

server.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Congrats, nothing broke!! Listening on port %d', server.address().port);
});
```

In my client file, the script are as follows:

```
<script src="my_path_to/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
var socket = io.connect();

var socketId = '';

socket.on('welcome', function (data) {
    socketId = data.message;
});
</script>
```

I also tried io.connect to `"http://localhost"`, `"http://localhost:3000"`, and my Heroku app domain. All of them produces the same error.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I did. But either I didn't get it or updating express in heroku didn't work for me

Comment: i'm sorry i don't use heroku. it used to have some issues with sockets back then, i don't know if it is still true now. but can't help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue ends up to be a express one, which has since been corrected in versions after `4.10.0`.

For your own reading:
https://github.com/strongloop/express/issues/2406
https://github.com/jshttp/on-finished/issues/10

Answer (score 0):

Look like you change socket.io path. Because I saw `src="my_path_to/socket.io.js"`. socket.io try to connect but got 404.

Is there a route of express handled '/socket.io/'?

Even you resolve the 404 error. You will hit the other error. Because currently on heroku you must set socket.io connect to a https address. Otherwise socket.io will work under polling.

More detail:
https://github.com/Automattic/engine.io/issues/261

Comment: thanks for your comment. Yup indeed there is a "catchall" route handler. I however did tried to disable the route from handling socketio.

`router.get('/:user', function(req, res, next) {

    if(req.params.user === 'socket.io') {
        return next(err);
    }
});`


I thought polling is used by socket.io by default?

Comment: socket.io 1.x has two default transport ['polling', 'websocket']. it first using polling connect to server. then server tell client:'you need upgrade (HTTP Status 100)'. client receive this then upgrade. upgrade action happen in one http request. include emit data later. all in one connect. the issue is heroku don't support sticky connect like this without SSL.